# Why do my page elements all come in from the top left when the page loads?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I've made two web page layouts which I'm very pleased with (you can view them at [Nursery](http://www.arthiaravind.com/nursery/) and [Rainforest](http://www.arthiaravind.com/rainforest/)). They work how I want them to and I think the coding is fine.

However, when the pages load in Chrome, the page elements will sometimes animate in from the top left (it doesn't happen all the time; I think it's just when the page loads for the first time maybe?) The menu bar buttons, the headers, the images, everything. It looks like they're sliding in as if they're a Powerpoint animation.

This looks ridiculous and I have no idea why it's happening. People I show the web pages to think it's an intentional animation, but it's not! It looks so silly. I have also observed it happening in Firefox. Does anyone know why it's happening and how I can prevent it? Thank you!

edit: I made another layout for another website (which has not been uploaded) and some of the elements on the bottom come in from the bottom, even though it isn't the first time the page is being loaded. Again, the layout coding is fine, but when the page loads, the elements animate in rather than just already appearing on the page.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's CSS. Have a look at this rule:
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out 0s;

You probably only want to transition the color, but it's also transitioning position.

Comment: Thank you; I think that is possibly it because when I removed the transitions from the elements' CSS, the problem was solved. However, I want the color to fade in and fade out smoothly, and when I remove the transitions from the element and not its hover, the color fades in nicely, but doesn't fade out -- it just changes with no transition at all. How can I made the color fade in AND out smoothly?